# aggregation with union c#

Tags: c#, linq, expression, aggregate

having some issues with aggregation. I'm trying to find all users that are subscribed to a certain skill and I'm using the following to do so:

```
IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> newUsers = _event.Skills
  .Aggregate(subscribedUsers, 
            (current, skill) => 
              _applicationUserService.GetUsers()
                 .Where(c => c.SubscribedSkills.Contains(skill))
  .Union(current));
```

Where I instantiate subscribedUsers as an empty list.

Comment: Why are you using aggregation? A simple `Where()` should do.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Hey guys, sorry about this. I figured out that the Contains(skill) was what was going wrong, because I needed to access the enumeration inside of it. Thanks though!

Comment: Also, I'm doing an aggregation because there are multiple skills I need to filter through.